# Webrtc stream local video file

Tags: webrtc, janus-gateway

How would one stream a local media file(video file) to peers?( i am using janus-gateway - videoroom plugin for this ).

For audio there is webAudio, but what about the video?

Thanks!

**Update**: Maybe someone has an example? Or a small code snippet? Maybe a link to some lib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Render the local video on Canvas & create stream object from Canvas element.
And then you can add the stream to PeerConnection.
Then stream will be sent to remote peer(Janus/Browser/any server).

**Demo:** https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-pc/

**Source:** https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/capture/canvas-pc/js/main.js#L45

Comment: I will try this! Thanks for the response!

Comment: I see that canvas can't play sound... I need to stream the video WITH the audio.

Comment: And browser compatability is a bit bad.

Comment: use WebAudio for mixing audio and canvas for video, then add AudioTrack (from webaudio audio stream) to video stream.